# How to show error when passing wrong prop type?

Tags: typescript, quasar-framework

I have a project on quasar with typescript support and i want to show errors when i pass wrong props value to my button component. For example i have prop named size with available values ['S', 'M', 'L'] but when i pass a random text nothing happend what should i do to show error right in code or don't compile code until i fix this error?

here is my button component

```
<template>
  <q-btn
    class="button"
    :label="label"
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { PropType } from 'vue';

defineProps({
  size: {
    type: String as PropType<'S' | 'M' | 'L'>,
    default: 'S',
    validator(value: string) {
      return ['S', 'M', 'L'].includes(value);
    },
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
});

</script>
```

And this is where i using wrong prop type

```
<template>
  <q-page class="row items-center justify-evenly">
    <TelepackButton
      label="Кнопка"
      size="fdsfsdfR"
    />
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import TelepackButton from 'components/TelepackButton/TelepackButton.vue';

</script>
```

Comment: What's your Typescript version?

Comment: Docs says it's buggy on TS<4.7

Comment: I'm using ts 4.9.4. Can you please share link on docs because i didn't find this information